# Poetry install fails when env variables are not in the same line

Tags: python-poetry

```
POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME=<username> POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=<password> poetry install
```

works but

```
export POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME=<username>
export POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=<password>
poetry install
```

fails with authentication error. Why? In both cases poetry should be able to read these variables, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should. Can you try to execute `env | grep POETRY` after the two export to check if the env vars are properly set?